# Admin Form fetch values from Database and keep it selected in dropdown

Tags: adminform

I have a custom module in admin, where I am display values in dropdown format something like below using `addField` function.

```
<select onchange="checkSelectedBean(this.value)" class="required-entry select" name="nic_id" id="nic_id">
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>
<option value="1_1.1">America</option>
<option value="2_2.2">China</option>
<option value="3_3.3">India</option>
<option value="4_4.4">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Here `4` is the **ID** for `Japan` and `4.4` is its unique value.

Now, If I select `Japan` as an option and save it, I have split the post value i.e. `4_4.4` and the value saved in DB is `4` which is okay. But when I edit the same record its not showing me the saved option `Japan` but dropdown list of all options.

I need to know how can I make `Japan` as selected option in dropdown, when admin edits the same record.

Right now its showing me the dropdown list only and not the saved option.

I am fetching value from my `Model/Nic.php` like below.

```
public function toOptionArray()
         {

          $nicCollection = Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->getCollection();

          $nicarray = array(array('value'=>-1, 'label'=>'Please Select'));

          foreach ($nicCollection as $nicList){

                $nicarray[] = array('value'=>$nicList['nic_id']._.$nicList['nic_cost'],'label'=>$nicList['nic_name']);
          }

          return $nicarray;

        }
```

Admin form to fetch selected dropdown with values

```
$fieldset->addField('nic_id', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('nic')->__('Nic'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'values'    => Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->toOptionArray(),
          'name'      => 'nic_id',
          ));
```

Pls Help.

Thanks.

Comment: is this option tags are hard coded or it is dynamic with php code ?

Comment: Please see my edited question. They are dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="<?php echo $nicarray['value']; ?>" <?php if($value_from_db == $nicarray['value']): echo "selected=selected"; else: ""; endif; ?> ><?php echo $nicarray['label']; ?></option>
```

Replace the array variable with actual array which you are using

here $value_from_db is the variable which is storing the selcted value.as you said some variable above giving value as 4.use that variable

Comment: I know the logic and how to make it selected. But I need to know how we do it in Magento.

Comment: see in the answer.if the db value and option array value are same when it is in the foreach loop then i had echo selected="selected". This will make the option as selected.

Comment: But how you do it in Magento Admin Form ?

Comment: ok can you post your magento form code please.i can help you.

Comment: Okay, pls see my edited question with `addField` code